# Serve GeoServer Tiles in XYZ format

Tags: openlayers-3, tiles, geoserver

I am using GeoServer and seed tiles on my server. The tiles are created successfully but i dont know which pattern the directory structure is following... (i.e. .../EPSG_4326_05/0_0/00_06.png)
I want to use the tiles in a OpenLayers application and there i want to use a OSM source which is using the XYZ-pattern which is commonly used as URL pattern for tile-serving.
Is there a way to tell the geoserver it should create the tiles with the XYZ structure?

Comment: Posted the question on gis.stackexchange.com: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242389/serve-geoserver-tiles-in-xyz-format

Answer (score 7):

Cool, I had the same question one hour ago. Here goes the summary.

Note:

> What the OP calls `XYZ` format is the format popularized by Google Maps where a global/basemap is server-side split and served as tiles in a `{z}/{x}/{y}` format where zoom, latitude and longitude are represented internally [1].
>   Effectively, the name of the service providing such "format" is `Tile Map Service (TMS)`[2], and GeoServer does provide such service [3].
>   `XYZ` is just the name of the class in OpenLayers used to access a `TMS` server [4].

That being said, here is how you'd do to have a TMS service running between your GeoServer and OpenLayers:

- Check if your GeoServer' *Caching Defaults* has GeoWebCache and the TMS service enabled. I am currently using GS-2.14.3 and those are enabled by default.

With GWC and TMS enabled you should see your raster layers listed under `http://localhost:8080/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0` (or, in general, `<geoserver-path>/gmc/service/tms/1.0.0`).

Then, you just have to call one of those *TileMaps* from OpenLayer:

```js
var tileURL = "<tilemap-from-gwc-list-above>" + "/{z}/{x}/{-y}.jpg" // or '.png'

var map = new ol.Map(<your params here>);

var bm = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: tileURL
  })
})
map.addLayer(bm)
```

Hope that helps.
Cheers.

---

Refs:

1. Google/TMS format: https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/
2. TMS specification: https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification
3. TMS in Leaflet: https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html#tms-in-leaflet
4. TMS/XYZ OpenLayers: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html

Answer (score 5):

This may be too late by here is my XYZ URL for geoserver layer:

```
http://localhost/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/gis:service@EPSG%3A900913@png/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png
```

Geoserver will cache the tiles automatically as you request through URL.

Comment: Can you provide a pointer to documentation? Do I need some extension to have the `tms` end point available? I've tried different urls, with no luck, like `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/tms/`, `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/`.

Comment: Just found out: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0`. Documentation available at: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/defaults.html.

Comment: Sorry took so long to respond. But yes thats the link ;)

Answer (score 0):

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) (actually [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/)) can provides a [number of end points](http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/index.html) that can server tiles.

None of these uses the so called XYZ system (because that isn't a standard) but [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) has a Tiled Layer that can handle TMS and WMTS servers using the [TileImage source](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileImage.html).

Comment: It would be important to serve the tiles as images just using our nginx-server. If i use the WMTS source of openlayers, serving the tiles would be done via geoserver and tomcat.. i just want to serve the tiles as simple images

Comment: I've never tried but I think that OpenLayers using a REST wmts (or TMS) scheme can read those tiles directly.

Comment: its supported now ... like other answers suggest