# How to add tms layer in openlayer 6?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

I used OpenLayer2, Mapproxy, Mapnik and tilecache for generating map. I added TMS layers in openlayer2.
Now I want to upgrade my openlayer, for that I chose latest version ol6.
How do I add a TMS layer in ol6.

My openlayer 2 js is like this

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS('District', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/tms/', {layername: 'district/distgrid', type: 'png', isBaseLayer:true,transitionEffect:"resize" });
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenLayers TMS layers are [tile layers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile-TileLayer.html) using a [XYZ source](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html):

```
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
  })
});
```

However, I am not sure about the properties you have provided (please check the docs). Read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55807135/2436655).

Comment: I can't import TileLayer or anything, getting error. Is the 'ol/layer' the folder path or syntax ? when I use new ***ol.layer.Tile*** there is no error. Can I use that ?

Comment: Take a look at _node_modules/ol/layer/Tile.js_. This should be the import path (minus the extension).

Comment: Oh, my bad. Do you use JavaScript or TypeScript? If first, than `new ol.layer.Tile` should be fine.

Comment: thanks alot..it worked..I have a doubt, I gave tile url like http://127.0.0.1:8080/tms/1.0.0/district/distgrid" + "/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png. Is it okay to gave 1.0.0 in url? anyway its working now

Comment: Your URL is totally fine. Glad I could help :)